# Mulesoft Salesforce connector insert multiple object records

Tags: salesforce, mule, anypoint-studio, mule4

We are using Mule4. Ask is that an SFTP server has a csv file which has multiple columns. Lets say there are following two columns - Email, TerminationDate. And there is ton of data (rows) for those columns.

Mulesoft needs to pick that csv file up and insert the data in salesforce (So we are using salesforce connector for it).

Problem is, data from column "Email" needs to go to a different object, and "TerminationDate" needs to be mapped to a different object.

```
CSV Columns <------ Mapped to ------> Salesforce object.Field
Email  <---------> Object1.Email__c
TerminationDate  <----------> Object2.TerminationDate__c
```

There is no way for me to split csv into multiple csvs beforehand. Thats just how we are getting the data.

I don't know how to proceed with it. Is it even possible? Most of the documentation/posts are see are about mapping things on to the fields of a single object. Any suggestions, pointers to documentations, etc will help.

I am able to map things to fields of a single object, but not sure how to proceed with multiple object requirement.

Comment: Can't you just reuse same file in two jobs? Is there some relation between the two objects in SF that you have to respect/create? No idea if you can reuse "success" log file of 1 operation in another operation... If you'll mark email on object1 as external id then it can be used instead of SF primary key for relationship mapping in "upsert" operation.

Comment: Capture Incoming fields into 2 different variables and have 2 connectors for each object insert `ex: vars.vEmail and vars.vTerminationDate`. you can achieve this in single dataweave. However, your source data doesn't seem to have referential integrity.